# Display the loadlib at runtime

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos

Currently in my shop, we have a standard SYSOUT header that displays a bunch of useful information such as:

- Program name
- Environment
- Start time
- When the program was compiled

One thing that would be very useful for us would be to display which load library the current program is running from. I was able to get the compile datetime using the IBM intrinsic function `WHEN-COMPILED`, but I am unable to find anything that will get me the loadlib.

What would be the proper way to approach this?

Comment: It might be a much simpler task if you simply show the datasets allocated to your job's STEPLIB. This is much easier than trying to deduce the actual library your program was loaded from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I see on the ibm-main listserv, there is no general solution to this problem that will work in all cases.  Having said that, your specific case might have a solution as suggested by Peter Relson at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bit.listserv.ibm-main/-kkUfvDpprk/L5PHW_HOyxMJ:

Mimic the system search order and do a BLDL on each dataset for the member in question.  When you find the member, you might know which library it was loaded from.  I say "might" because maybe the member was loaded and then someone deleted it from the library.  And maybe then added it to different library.

If you follow the discussion thread you will see one member succeeded in creating an Assembler module to do what I think you're asking about.  Maybe they would be willing to share their code, or already have on the CBTTAPE site.

Comment: that link was super informative. I'll give it a bit more time before I accept this answer. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Just wanted to add that there *is* a definitive solution, but it takes a lot of coding. The idea is to trap all the various CSV calls from an application (say, subsystem SVC screening), figure out where you think the module should come from, then force the LINK/LOAD/ATTACH/etc to use the one you found. This solves the issue of a module moving between load and when you look it up.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to take a console dump and view the current load module open. Once you have that, you can compare the date-time stamp with the different loadlibs to find the the loadlib.

1.In SDSF,
Console Dump DUMP COMM=(loop dump). This will return with the ID.

2.Enter the command:
 R id,JOBNAME=(your_jobname),SDATA=(CSA,GRSQ,LPA,LSQA,NUC,PSA,RGN,SQA,SWA,TRT),END

3.import the dump into abend-aid

4.Find the module you are interested in

5.Compare the date time with your different loadlibs